# How to read a txt file, get a data and store it as variable in Custom Properties of SOAPUI using Groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

i started to use Soapui this week and i did some tests like sending a request POST and save the response as txt file ina folder.
What i'm trying to do is to read this txt file, copy a sepcific data and store it in Custom Properties.
Because i want to use this object in the nest Request POST which is depending of the first request.

I want to do it in Groovy.
i have only the Open source SOAPUI version 5.0.0

Thank you

Comment: what part of this tasks troubles you?  what have you already tried?

Comment: Why do you want to store it .txt file? Isn't it easier to Property Transfer Step? You get needed values fro response and transfer them to the next request.

Comment: Please can you explain with example, thqnk you i will look in google too

Answer (score 2):

You've to add a `groovy` test step in your test case and do it similar as you would in java, check [groovy documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/).

Only as a reference SOAPUI 5.2.0 has the `groovy` 2.1.7 version [(check the dependency in pom.xml)](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/blob/next/soapui/pom.xml) so in `groovy` scripts which runs on SOAPUI you can use the java standard api included in the `jre`, the SOAPUI classes, the [`groovy` 2.1.7 API](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.1.7/html/gapi/index.html?overview-summary.html) among some others, additionally you can include other jars in `SOAPUI\bin\ext` in order to use them in `groovy` script.

Finally you're asking about to read some data from a file and write it to a custom property, so for example you can do it as follows:

```
// read the file from path
def file = new File('/path/yourFile')
// for example read line by line
def yourData = file.eachLine { line ->
    // check if the line contains your data 
    if(line.contains('mySpecifiyData=')){
        return line
    }
}

// put the line in a custom property in the testCase
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('yourProp',yourData)
```

Since your problem it's not clear I show you a possible sample showing how to read a file looking for specific content and saving this content in a custom property in the testCase.

Note that in `groovy` scripts the are a global objects which you can use: `testRunner`, `context` and `log`, in this sample I use `testRunner` to access `testCase` and its properties, in the same way you can go thought `testRunner` to access `testSuites`, `project`, `testSteps` etc... check the documentation:

1. http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html
2. http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-scripts.html

Hope this helps,